# High CPU & High Number of Timers

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, windbg

I am seeing high CPU on my server. I took a crash dump and fired up windbg.

I am getting following but not sure what to make of it:

```
From !runaway
Top 5 thread related to CPU`enter code here`
  Thread       Time
  33:1758      0 days 0:08:58.109
  24:128c      0 days 0:05:09.531
  25:15b0      0 days 0:04:53.281
  23:a94       0 days 0:04:50.343
  26:bf8       0 days 0:04:48.984
```

from !threadpool

```
0:000> !threadpool
CPU utilization 100%
Worker Thread: Total: 18 Running: 17 Idle: 1 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 4
Work Request in Queue: 4
AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion TimerInfo@159b81b8
AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion TimerInfo@185e48a8
Unknown Function: 6a2aa293  Context: 3a1bc2e0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 30
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit: 0 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 4
0:000> !threads
ThreadCount: 56
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 56
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 0
Hosted Runtime: no
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is the call-stack looks like for Thread 33 which has the highest CPU time? You could do "!Clrstack;kb" to get Managed and native call-stacks.

Comment: so I have crash dump from two sources. default app pool and service app server. default app pool has 5 threads (21,22,23,24,41) with high cpu and service app server has one thread (33) with high cpu. we have taken dump two times and both time it is true. this is the call stack from default app pool thread 41

Comment: I have no idea how to put whole stack here. is there a way to attach the file

Answer (score 0):

A single dump is useless. You need to capture several hang dumps with one minute interval each, and then use !runaway to find the culprit. After that !CLRStack and kb can show you more info about that thread.

Comment: there is nothing with callstack but with KB I got following

Comment: ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child18c4f31c 75f51270 000005fc 00000000 18c4f364 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15

Comment: `0:033> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
18c4f31c 75f51270 000005fc 00000000 18c4f364 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15....
18c4f38c 72e2553f 000005fc 00001388 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xbe....18c4f3d0 72e2548b 000005fc 00001388 00000000 mscorwks!PEImage::LoadImage+0x1af...18c4f420 72e254aa 00001388 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x117..18c4f434 72e639b3 00001388 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17..18c4f4b4 7310fc02 01a67650 00001388 00000000 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::SafeWait+0x73`

Comment: some more '18c4f4dc 7310fdbd b71206d7 00000000 72e63d69 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::EnterRetirement+0x5d...18c4f534 72f86ec9 00000000 fffde000 00000001 mscorwks!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x325..18c4f8d4 75fceccb 158f4e68 18c4f920 778dd80d mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49...18c4f8e0 778dd80d 158f4e68 4932c7db 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe...18c4f920 778dda1f 72f86e83 158f4e68 ffffffff ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x23...18c4f938 00000000 72f86e83 158f4e68 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

Comment: Like I said, you need multiple dumps, and then compare !runaway results so as to know which thread ate the CPU. Only after that the call stacks can help locate the culprit.

Comment: I have got another dump but it shows same behaviour. it has the same call stack.

Comment: What is the time difference between the two dumps? If the time interval is too short or too long, both of them cannot tell who is the culprit and you need to recapture. Have you carefully compared the !runaway results of the two dumps? Is thread 33 the one that consumed all CPU in the time interval? I can hardly believe a thread that waited on ZwWaitForSingleObject consumed too much CPU.

Comment: @Chito, if you are not familiar with dump analysis and wish to have this culprit located sooner, please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. Dump analysis is not something you can learn within a few days.

Comment: we did open up a ticket at MSFT.  but that does not mean that that we just wait for our savior and help us. as we both have the same information. Offcourse, I am new to this. but if I do not start then when I learn.